# find letters from a string in a list

Tags: python, string, list, for-loop, boolean

write a function that takes as an argument a list and a string, and returns a boolean based on whether or not all the letters in the string appear somewhere in the list.

```
my_function(["hello","world"],"hold")
```

should return `True`
and

```
my_function(["hello","world"],"down")
```

should return `False`

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Is `heel` `True`?

Comment: Convert them both to a set of characters, and check that the first one is a superset of the second one.

Comment: And your problem? This is only an enunciate of a basic problem. This isn't a service of tutorization. Please show us that you have tried, you musn't only wait for a solution.

Answer (score 0):

This function will take in the input `arr` and `string` and compute, as you would expect.  To explain the code, I start by building an 'index' to compare against, I called it, `di`.  From there I loop through every character of every string inside of `arr`.  From there, if they are all true, then return true, otherwise false.  As for how that comparison was written (`all(di[key] for key in di`) it builds a true and false tuple and then `all` checks if all items in the list-like item are true.

```
def my_function(arr,string):
    di = {c:False for c in string}
    for value in arr:
        for character in value:
            if character in di:
                di[character] = True
    return all(di[key] for key in di)
```